# How to force close a Realm database with Swift SDK?

Tags: swift, realm

According to the documentation, `close` is not available in Swift SDK.

> There is no need to manually close a realm in Swift or Objective-C. When a realm goes out of scope and is removed from memory due to
> ARC , the realm is closed.

However when handling a user logout use case, after the user logged out and try to log in again the Realm through a "Realm at path XXX already opened with different sync user."

Apparently `user.logOut` would not close the Realm for me and I do not think I have any previous Realm ref stored in the memory.

I have even tried to delete the Realm database file associated with the sync user but once the user got re-logged into the app. The same error appears.

Comment: This is a  good question but the documentation is quite literal; *A Realm goes out of scope in code when ALL references to it go out of scope*. e.g. logging out a user has nothing to do with references to Realm going out of scope. e.g. a user could be logged out but you still maintain some reference to the Realm elsewhere in your code `let realm = try! Realm` in a singleton for example.

Comment: if you're using an actor-isolated realm, it doesn't seem to auto-close